# create compute instance on sole tenant node using Terraform in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I need help to create google compute instance on sole tenant node using Terraform. I am able to create compute instance GCE on multi tenant node but not finding information about how to create instance using Terraform in sole tenant node.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sole tenant node GCE instance via "node_type" argument.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_node_template

According to this Terraform document, It desribes example usage like this.

```
   resource "google_compute_node_template" "template" {
     provider = google-beta

     name      = "soletenant-with-licenses"
     region    = "us-central1"
     node_type = "n1-node-96-624" # here is sole-tenant node type argument
     }
```

Here is sole tenent node type list at Google document.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes#node_types

You can specify sole tenant node type you want via node_type argument value like "m1-node-96-1433", "n1-node-96-624" etc...

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, Actually I have created sole tenant node using same code .but I am looking for TF code to create compute instance on sole tenant node (GCE on sole tenant)

Comment: You can create GCE instances on sole tenant nodes via creating normal GCE instance method. But you need to specify "node_config" argument. 
Example code here :https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/2700

Comment: Plus, Refer to this document to provisioning VMs on sole-tenant nodes.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/create-nodes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you if you have achieved the same, but here is the way to do so. You will need Node-affinity parameter in the google_compute_instance resource.

```
resource "google_compute_node_template" "template" {
...

scheduling  {
    automatic_restart = "true"
    node_affinities  {
      key = "compute.googleapis.com/node-group-name"
      operator = "IN"
      values = ["${var.solenodegroup}"] #Replace it with the Sole Tenant Group Name.
    }

    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"

    preemptible = false
  }

}
```

Note- You will need to set the machine type matching to the sole tenant group machine type.